# C++/Fortran mixed programming: undefined reference to `_gfortran_reshape_r8'

Tags: c++, fortran, mixed-code

I am compiling a C++ code together with Fortran subroutine. The C++ cpp code is like:

```
#include "Calculate.h"
extern "C" double SolveEq_(double *Gvalue, double *GvalueU, double *GvalueV, double *Gnodex, double *Gnodey, double *GtimeInc, double *Glfs);

template <class T1, class T2>
void Calculate(vector<Element<T1, T2> > &elm, GParameter &GeqPm, GmeshInfo &Gmesh)
{
    // Solving Equation using Fortran code
    SolveEq_(&Gmesh.Gvalue[0], &Gmesh.GvalueU[0], &Gmesh.GvalueV[0], &Gmesh.Gnodex[0], &Gmesh.Gnodey[0], &GeqPm.GtimeInc, &GeqPm.Glfs);
    return;
}
```

And the Fortran code is like:

```
!==========================================================================
Module Inputpar
Implicit None
Integer,parameter :: Numx = 200, Numy = 200
End Module
!======================================== PROGRAM =============================================
Subroutine SolveEq(Gvalue, GvalueU, GvalueV, Gnodex, Gnodey, Deltat, Lfs);
Use Inputpar
Implicit None

Real*8 Deltat, Lfs, Dt, Su
Real*8 Gvalue(1, (Numx+1)*(Numy+1)), GvalueU(1, (Numx+1)*(Numy+1)), GvalueV(1, (Numx+1)*(Numy+1))
Real*8 Gnodex(0:Numx), Gnodey(0:Numy)

Real*8 DX, DY
Real*8 X(-3:Numx+3), Y(-3:Numy+3)
Real*8 VelX(-3:Numx+3,-3:Numy+3), VelY(-3:Numx+3,-3:Numy+3)
Real*8 G(-3:Numx+3,-3:Numy+3)

Common /CommonData/ X, Y, DX, DY, VelX, VelY, G, Dt, Su

!============================= Data Transfer ============================
Dt                  = Deltat
Su                  = Lfs
X          (0:Numx) = Gnodex(0:Numx)
Y          (0:Numy) = Gnodey(0:Numy)
VelX(0:Numx,0:Numy) = transpose(reshape(GvalueU,(/Numy+1,Numx+1/)))
VelY(0:Numx,0:Numy) = transpose(reshape(GvalueV,(/Numy+1,Numx+1/)))
G   (0:Numx,0:Numy) = transpose(reshape(Gvalue ,(/Numy+1,Numx+1/)))

!==========Some other lines neglected here=================

End
!======================================== END PROGRAM =========================================
```

Firstly compile the Fortran code using command:

```
      gfortran SolveEq.f90 -c -o SolveEq.o
```

And then compile the C++/Fortran codes together using makefile:

```
# Compiler
CC = g++

# Debug option
DEBUG = false

# Source directory of codes
SRC1 = /home
SRC2 = $(SRC1)/Resources
SRC3 = $(SRC1)/Resources/Classes

OPT=-fopenmp -O2

ifdef $(DEBUG)
  PROG=test.out
else
  PROG=i.out
endif

# Linker
#LNK=-I$(MPI)/include -L$(MPI)/lib -lmpich -lopa -lmpl -lpthread

OBJS = libtseutil.a Calculate.o SolveEq.o

OBJS_F=$(OBJS)
SUF_OPTS1=$(OBJS_F)
SUF_OPTS2=-I$(SRC2)/
SUF_OPTS3=-I$(SRC3)/
SUF_OPTS4=

# Details of compiling
$(PROG): $(OBJS_F)
    $(CC) $(OPT) -o $@ $(SUF_OPTS1)
%.o: $(SRC1)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(OPT) -c $< $(SUF_OPTS2)
%.o: $(SRC2)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(OPT) -c $< $(SUF_OPTS3)
%.o: $(SRC3)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(OPT) -c $< $(SUF_OPTS4)

# Clean
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -rf *.o *.oo *.log
```

However, the error shows that:

```
g++ -fopenmp -O2 -o libtseutil.a Calculate.o SolveEq.o
Calculate.o: In function `void Calculate<CE_Tri, SolElm2d>(std::vector<Element<CE_Tri, SolElm2d>, std::allocator<Element<CE_Tri, SolElm2d> > >&, GParameter&, GmeshInfo&)':
Calculate.cpp:(.text._Z10CalculateGI6CE_Tri8SolElm2dEvRSt6vectorI7ElementIT_T0_ESaIS6_EER10GParameterR9GmeshInfo[_Z10CalculateGI6CE_Tri8SolElm2dEvRSt6vectorI7ElementIT_T0_ESaIS6_EER10GParameterR9GmeshInfo]+0x3c): undefined reference to `SolveEq_'
SolveEq.o: In function `solveeq_':
SolveEq.f90:(.text+0x2b8e): undefined reference to `_gfortran_reshape_r8'
SolveEq.f90:(.text+0x2d2a): undefined reference to `_gfortran_reshape_r8'
SolveEq.f90:(.text+0x2ec6): undefined reference to `_gfortran_reshape_r8'
SolveEq.f90:(.text+0x31fa): undefined reference to `_gfortran_reshape_r8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How does this happen?

I used a simple case to test the mixed compiling. The C++ code was:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

extern "C" double fortran_sum_(double *sum, double *su2m, double *vec, double* vec2, int *size);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int size;
    double sum, sum2;
    double aa,bb,cc,dd;
    vector<double> vec;
    vector<double> vec2;

    size=2;
    aa=1.0;
    bb=2.0;
    sum=0.0;
    sum2=0.0;

    vec.push_back(aa);
    vec.push_back(bb);
    vec2.push_back(aa*2.0);
    vec2.push_back(bb*2.0);

    fortran_sum_(&sum, &sum2, &vec[0], &vec2[0], &size);

    cout << "Calling a Fortran function" << endl;
    cout << "============================" << endl;
    cout << "size = " << size << endl;
    cout << "sum = " << sum << endl;
    cout << "sum2 = " << sum2 << endl << endl;
}
```

And the Fortran code was:

```
Subroutine fortran_sum(gsum, gsum2, gvec, gvec2, gsize2)
  integer gsize,gsize2
  real*8 gvec(0:gsize2-1), gvec2(0:1)
  real*8 gsum, gsum2
  gsum = gvec(0)+gvec(1);
  gsum2 = gvec2(0)+gvec2(1);
  gsize = gsize*2;
end
```

Then used commands to compile :

```
gfortran fortran_sum.f90 -c -o fortran_sum.o
g++ fortran_sum.o call_fortran.cpp -o a.out
./a.out
```

It worked well:

```
Calling a Fortran function
============================
size = 2
sum = 3
sum2 = 6
```

Comment: I used a simple case to test the mixed programming, the c++ code is :

Comment: Maybe you need to link with libgfortran?

Comment: @ZetianRen, Do you have *nm* or *objdump* or any such tools in your compiler collection (Or Operating system provided)? You can look into the the fortran_sum.o to see if the SolveEq_ is there (or if it has some other variant name for it).

Comment: @RobertPrévost  Put this in Linker line of makefile?

Comment: @blackpen Sorry I can't get your point. But the two cases are in different folders.

Comment: @ZetianRen yeah, try adding -lgfortran to the link line.

Answer (score 1):

The function `_gfortran_reshape_r8` is part of the library that is used by code compiled by `gfortran`.  When you compile in a single language such libraries are automatically linked because whichever program you use to do the linking knows about them.  When you link mixed code, you need to find and explicitly put on the command line the libraries for the language that doesn't correspond to the linker you've chosen.  Usually you link with the C++ syntax, as you've done here, and add the fortran compiler's libraries explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. You mean that I should edit my Linker line in the makefile?

Comment: Yes, you will need to find the library that contains the Fortran libraries and put that into the linker command line with a `-L` flag.  You'll also need to include the individual libraries with corresponding `-l` flags.

Comment: From the comments on your question, it looks like the specific library you need is `libgfortran`, so find that and put the directory in with the `-L` flag (as you've done for other packages in your example), and then have `-lgfortran` also.  You may find that you need more libraries, but `gfortran` sounds right. (I've done this before but not recently.)

Comment: Thanks! I finally added -lgfortran and it compiled successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I am little bit weak on Fortran language. When I compiled your fortran code and put it through nm, it gave me the following. There is no symbol "SolveEq_". There is just "solveeq_".

```
0000000000000020 r A.15.3480
0000000000000000 r A.3.3436
0000000000000010 r A.9.3463
                 U _gfortran_reshape_r8
00000000000fbe28 C commondata_
                 U free
                 U malloc
0000000000000000 T solveeq_
```

---

Edit:
It compiled for me when I used "solveeq_". Here is simplified code for demo (main.cpp):

```
extern "C" double solveeq_(
              double *Gvalue, double *GvalueU, 
              double *GvalueV, double *Gnodex, 
              double *Gnodey, double *GtimeInc, double *Glfs
           );

template <typename T>
void Calculate(T *one, T *two, T *three,
               T *four, T *five, T *six, T *seven) {
    solveeq_(one,two,three,four,five,six,seven);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
     double one,two,three,four,five,six,seven;
     Calculate<double>(&one,&two,&three,&four,&five,&six,&seven);
}
```

Compiled it as (f.f90 has the fortran code):

```
gfortran -c f.f90
g++ f.o main.cpp -lgfortran
```

---

It seems, since 2003, if you want to call a fortran function from C/C++, you could use BIND (It may not with fortran/fortran though without some more additional effort).

```
Subroutine SolveEq(F) BIND(C,NAME="SolveMyEquation")
Real Gvalue, GvalueU, GvalueV, Gnodex, Gnodey, Deltat, Lfs
End
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed the function name into solveeq.f90, which is all in small letters, and it got through.

Comment: Fortran is insensitive to case. Depending on the compiler, all symbols typically get converted to either all caps or all lower in the assembly.  Also depending on compiler and the function name, you may get 0, 1, or two underscores added to the symbol name.  You need to take this into account when doing the linking between languages, but I emphasize that it is compiler dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to every one, especially @Brick and @blackpen.
The problem has been fixed.

1), Add -lgfortran into command line so that the function,otherwise it will show: undefined reference to `_gfortran_reshape_r8'.

2), Change the name of the .f90 function into small letters "solveeq" other wise it will show: undefined reference to `SolveGeq_'

So finally my .cpp is changed into :

```
#include "Calculate.h"
extern "C" void solveeq_(double *Gvalue, double *GvalueU, double *GvalueV, double *Gnodex, double *Gnodey, double *GtimeInc, double *Glfs);

template <class T1, class T2>
void Calculate(vector<Element<T1, T2> > &elm, GParameter &GeqPm, GmeshInfo &Gmesh)
{
    // Solving Equation using Fortran code
    solveeq_(&Gmesh.Gvalue[0], &Gmesh.GvalueU[0], &Gmesh.GvalueV[0], &Gmesh.Gnodex[0], &Gmesh.Gnodey[0], &GeqPm.GtimeInc, &GeqPm.Glfs);
    return;
}
```

The fortran code .f90 is like:

```
!==========================================================================
Module Inputpar
Implicit None
Integer,parameter :: Numx = 200, Numy = 200
End Module
!======================================== PROGRAM =============================================
Subroutine SolveEq(Gvalue, GvalueU, GvalueV, Gnodex, Gnodey, Deltat, Lfs);
Use Inputpar
Implicit None

Real*8 Deltat, Lfs, Dt, Su
Real*8 Gvalue(1, (Numx+1)*(Numy+1)), GvalueU(1, (Numx+1)*(Numy+1)), GvalueV(1, (Numx+1)*(Numy+1))
Real*8 Gnodex(0:Numx), Gnodey(0:Numy)

Real*8 DX, DY
Real*8 X(-3:Numx+3), Y(-3:Numy+3)
Real*8 VelX(-3:Numx+3,-3:Numy+3), VelY(-3:Numx+3,-3:Numy+3)
Real*8 G(-3:Numx+3,-3:Numy+3)

Common /CommonData/ X, Y, DX, DY, VelX, VelY, G, Dt, Su

!============================= Data Transfer ============================
Dt                  = Deltat
Su                  = Lfs
X          (0:Numx) = Gnodex(0:Numx)
Y          (0:Numy) = Gnodey(0:Numy)
VelX(0:Numx,0:Numy) = transpose(reshape(GvalueU,(/Numy+1,Numx+1/)))
VelY(0:Numx,0:Numy) = transpose(reshape(GvalueV,(/Numy+1,Numx+1/)))
G   (0:Numx,0:Numy) = transpose(reshape(Gvalue ,(/Numy+1,Numx+1/)))

!==========Some other lines neglected here=================

End
!======================================== END PROGRAM =========================================
```

And the makefile is like：

```
# Compiler
CC = g++

# Debug option
DEBUG = false

# Source directory of codes
SRC1 = /home
SRC2 = $(SRC1)/Resources
SRC3 = $(SRC1)/Resources/Classes

OPT=-fopenmp -O2

ifdef $(DEBUG)
  PROG=test.out
else
  PROG=i.out
endif

# Linker
#LNK=-I$(MPI)/include -L$(MPI)/lib -lmpich -lopa -lmpl -lpthread

OBJS = libtseutil.a Calculate.o solveeq.o

OBJS_F=$(OBJS)
SUF_OPTS1=$(OBJS_F)
SUF_OPTS2=-I$(SRC2)/
SUF_OPTS3=-I$(SRC3)/
SUF_OPTS4=

# Details of compiling
$(PROG): $(OBJS_F)
    $(CC) $(OPT) -o $@ $(SUF_OPTS1)
%.o: $(SRC1)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(OPT) -c $< $(SUF_OPTS2)
%.o: $(SRC2)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(OPT) -c $< $(SUF_OPTS3)
%.o: $(SRC3)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(OPT) -c $< $(SUF_OPTS4)
solveeq.o: $(SRC1)/solveeq.f90
    gfortran -c $<

# Clean
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -rf *.o *.oo *.log
```

Comment: See my related comment about the case of the function names on the answer by @blackpen.