# undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'

Tags: windows, fortran, cygwin, gfortran

==================================== The following command line for a "hello world"

```
program 

/usr/bin/gfortran -std=f95 -Wextra -Wall -O2 -c main.for
```

==================================== produces the following errors.

```
cc -std=f95 -Wextra -Wall -O2  main.o -o main
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: main.o: in function `MAIN__':
main.for:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: main.for:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: main.for:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: main.for:(.text.startup+0x14): undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_options'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.for:(.text.startup+0x5): undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_args'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: main.for:(.text.startup+0x14): undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_options'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:44: main] Error 1
```

Comment: the `Hello world` example seems missing...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++/Fortran mixed programming: undefined reference to \`\_gfortran\_reshape\_r8'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239624/c-fortran-mixed-programming-undefined-reference-to-gfortran-reshape-r8)

Comment: Another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148378/gfortran-pow-c8-i4-error-when-linking-o-files-from-g-and-gfortran-using-g

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs on both windows+cygwin and on linux.

In both cases there were two versions of gfortran installed, the default V7 and a user configured V8.

Checking the installs with  >gfortran --version, worked worked in both cases (windows+cygwin and linux.), with no errors.

======================== My solution
was to first eradicate all versions of gfortran and then second, reinstall the default version.
I'm still figuring out how to install a user configured version.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to link gfortran library with -lgfortran

Comment: Why do you think so? How does that work? Why does it help?

Comment: @Yunnosch the missing symbol is from the libgfortran runtime library. This is a common problem with many duplicates.